# `push` from "connected-react-router" used in redux-observable epic doesn't change the url and renders empty page

Tags: react-router-v4, redux-observable, connected-react-router

`push` from "connected-react-router" used in redux-observable epic doesn't change the url and renders empty page. `state.router.location` never changes, so I think that the action does not get dispatched properly, but the components are not rendered any more - that's a change I can't figure out.

The app is as follows:

In reducers:

```
const rootReducer: Reducer<any, any> = history => combineReducers({
  router: connectRouter(history),
})
```

In app config:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: ROOT_PATH,
})

<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <RootContainer />
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>

const configureStore = (): Store => {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer(history),
    applyMiddleware(createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic)),
  )
}
```

In RootContainer.js

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"

const Root = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RootComponent))
export default Root
```

In epics:

```
import { push } from "connected-react-router"

const navigateTo = (action$: ActionsObservable<Action>): ActionsObservable<Action> => (
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(SharedActions.OPEN_WINDOW),
    mergeMap((action) => {
      return of(push(action.payload.url))
    }),
  )
)
```

package.json

```
"connected-react-router": "^5.0.1",
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-observable": "^0.17.0",
"rxjs": "^5.5.7",
```

I don't have any hot module replacement like in [this example](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/examples/basic/src/index.js), but I think it's not related.

**UPDATE:**

I've added epics to listen for:

```
import { CALL_HISTORY_METHOD, LOCATION_CHANGE, push } from "connected-react-router"
```

It seems that the following action gets dispatched:

```
{
  type: "@@router/CALL_HISTORY_METHOD"
  payload: {
    args: [ "new/path" ]
    method: "push"
  }
}
```

​
​It just doesn't have any effect on the url.

**UPDATE**

Also using Link (react-router-dom) to directly navigate to the "new/path" works great inside components, so the path is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may have forgotten to add the `routerMiddleware` when creating your Redux store:
https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router#step-2

Your app config above should be:

```js
import { routerMiddleware } from "connected-react-router";

const history = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: ROOT_PATH,
})

<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <RootContainer />
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>

const configureStore = (): Store => {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer(history),
    applyMiddleware(
      createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic),
      routerMiddleware(history),
    ),
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you add a piece of code that explains how to do this ?